# How to setup public Google calendar

Tags: calendar, google-workspace, google-calendar

I'd like to have my appointments Google calendar viewable by clients. However, I don't want them to view all the information, just if I'm available or not at a certain time.

Is there a way to make Google Calendar to only display available or non available information to users that are not members of my Google Apps account?

Comment: I think the Appointment Slots feature (http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190998) does most of this, but can different users of the appointments page see the details of each others appointments?

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Share this Calendar", tick "Make this calendar public", and "Share only my free/busy information". Then, under "Calendar Details" there's a section "Calendar Address" with links to XML, iCal, and HTML versions of the public calendar. You can embed the HTML into an iframe on your website, or just send people the link.